# Tkinter StringVar shows random numbers instead of variable on label

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pycharm

The title says it all.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, Text, StringVar

root = tk.Tk()

root.resizable(False, False)

var1 = StringVar()

topn = ""
print(topn)

def addApp():
    global topn
    topn = topn + "1"
    print(topn)
    var1.set(topn)



canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=500, width=400, bg="#263D42")
canvas.pack()

frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="orange")
frame.place(relwidth=0.8, relheight=0.8, relx=0.1, rely=0.1)

Resultlabel = tk.Label(root,text=var1.get,  padx=100, pady=5, fg="white", bg="grey")
Resultlabel.pack()
t
openFile = tk.Button(frame, text="Open File", padx=10, pady=5, fg="white", bg="#263D42", command=addApp)
openFile.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

[btw, ignore the Open File, i was following a tutorial to learn the basics of tkinter and then edited the code to fit my needs. I forgot to change the text in the button.]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FVKG.png

Comment: You want `textvariable=var1`.  `text=` just sets a static text string for the Label, but you didn't give it any sort of meaningful string.  `text=var1.get()` would have given you the contents of the StringVar as of that moment in time, but it wouldn't update automatically.

Comment: Try `text=var1.get()` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`text` is not the same thing as `textvariable`. `text` is used to associate static text with a widget, `textvariable` is used to have the text of the widget be synchronized with the value of a variable.

If you want `ResultLabel` to always show what is in `var1` you must define it like this:

```
Resultlabel = tk.Label(root,textvariable=var1,  padx=100, pady=5, fg="white", bg="grey")
```